# .Net-Core 2.2 MassTransit.ConfigurationException: The state machine was not properly configured

Tags: .net-core, masstransit, saga, automatonymous

Newbie question - what am I missing?  Are there any dotnetcore 2.2 Saga examples available?

I have a basic end to end system working OK with messages flowing across containers in docker-compose, but adding a Saga seems to be a challenge -

Q. Am I missing a scheduler dependency?  In MassTransit 5.5.5, cfg.UseInMemoryMessageScheduler(); doesn't compile.

Something odd was going on, I had to mark my state machine explicitly as ISaga

MassTransit.ConfigurationException: Failed to create the state machine connector for Model.WorkflowExecutionStateMachine ---> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: The state machine was not properly configured:
workflowapi_1  | [Failure] ExecutingTask was not specified

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // Register MassTransit
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<WorkflowTaskConsumer>();

            // required?
            x.AddSaga<WorkflowExecutionSaga>();

            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var rabbitMQHostName = $"rabbitmq://{configuration["RabbitMQHostName"]}";

                Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Starting Workflow Receiver... {rabbitMQHostName}/{QueueNames.ExeuteWorkflowTaskQueue}");

                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMQHostName), hostConfig =>
                {
                    hostConfig.Username("guest");
                    hostConfig.Password("guest");
                });

                // A basic message works OK
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, QueueNames.ExeuteWorkflowTaskQueue, ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 1;
                    ep.UseMessageRetry(mr => mr.Interval(1000, 2));
                    ep.ConfigureConsumer<WorkflowTaskConsumer>(provider);
                });

                // Doesn't like this
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, QueueNames.WorkflowStateMachineSagaQueueName, ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 1;
                    ep.UseMessageRetry(mr => mr.Interval(1000, 2));
                    ep.StateMachineSaga(new WorkflowExecutionSaga(), new InMemorySagaRepository<WorkflowExecutionStateMachine>());
                });
            }));

            cfg.UseInMemoryMessageScheduler(); // doesn't compile!
        });
    }
```

Bus is started as follows -

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, 
            // see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseMvc();

        var bus = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IBusControl>();
        var busHandle = TaskUtil.Await(() =>
        {
            return bus.StartAsync();
        });

        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
        {
            busHandle.Stop();
        });
    }
```

Exception details are

Unhandled Exception: MassTransit.ConfigurationException: Failed to create the state machine connector for Rapid.Workflow.Api.Model.WorkflowExecutionStateMachine ---> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: The state machine was not properly configured:
workflowapi_1  | [Failure] ExecutingTask was not specified
workflowapi_1  |    at Automatonymous.StateMachineConfigurationResult.CompileResults(IEnumerable`1 results)
workflowapi_1  |    at Automatonymous.StateMachineConnectors.StateMachineConnector`1.StateMachineEvents()+MoveNext()
workflowapi_1  |    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
workflowapi_1  |    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
workflowapi_1  |    at Automatonymous.StateMachineConnectors.StateMachineConnector`1..ctor(SagaStateMachine`1 stateMachine)
workflowapi_1  |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
workflowapi_1  |    at Automatonymous.StateMachineConnectors.StateMachineConnector`1..ctor(SagaStateMachine`1 stateMachine)
workflowapi_1  |    at Automatonymous.SagaConfigurators.StateMachineSagaConfigurator`1..ctor(SagaStateMachine`1 stateMachine, ISagaRepository`1 repository, ISagaConfigurationObserver observer)
workflowapi_1  |    at MassTransit.AutomatonymousReceiveEndpointExtensions.StateMachineSaga[TInstance](IReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator, SagaStateMachine`1 stateMachine, ISagaRepository`1 repository, Action`1 configure)
workflowapi_1  |    at Rapid.Workflow.Api.Startup.<>c.b__2_5(IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator ep) in /src/Workflow.Api/Startup.cs:line 74

Dependencies are

```
<PackageReference Include="Automatonymous" Version="4.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="5.5.5" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="5.5.5" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.5" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Automatonymous" Version="5.5.5" /> 
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.5.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
```

Thanks for any tips or ideas -

Comment: I've found an example ... https://github.com/selcukusta/masstransit-saga-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to crop up because the Saga class had declared some as-yet-unused (but public) events - DOH!

The solution was to remove unused events from the Saga...

```
// uncomment will fail! public Event<ISatelliteTaskRequest> UnusedEvent { get; private set; }
```

After looking at this sample https://github.com/selcukusta/masstransit-saga-implementation and cutting my program.cs back to basics - I was still getting the error! So, not a container / IOC / Startup issue.

Next, looking in source for the MassTransit error message (https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.AutomatonymousIntegration/Configuration/StateMachineConnectors/StateMachineConnector.cs) I realised that the correlating code is possibly reflecting on all public members of the Saga -

So, removing unused events from the Saga class fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes, events are discovered on the type - and if you haven't configured them with proper correlation, they'll cause an error. Would help if the error message was more descriptive though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change use the `.AddStateMachineSaga` method, instead of the `.AddSaga` method you're using in the code in question.

```
// required? - yes, but should be as shown here
x.AddSagaStateMachine<WorkflowExecutionSaga, WorkflowState>();
```

In this case, both the state machine and the state machine instance type are required. Then, in your endpoint, use:

```
ep.ConfigureSaga<WorkflowState>(provider);
```

You also need to make sure you have the saga repository configured in the container, which is done for MS DI/in-memory using:

```
x.AddSingleton<ISagaRepository<WorkflowState>, InMemorySagaRepository<WorkflowState>>();
```

That should get you rolling, assuming your state machine isn't broken. If you still get the error, make sure all your state machine events, etc. are properly configured.

Also, your state machine instance should implement:

```
public class WorkflowState :
    SagaStateMachineInstance
```

And your state machine does *not* need to implement `ISaga`.

```
public class WorkflowExecutionSaga :
    MassTransitStateMachine<WorkflowState>
```

Comment: Thanks - will check, and remove ISaga (I realised that MassTransitSaga inherits this... VS Code...!?)

Apologies for not posting my Saga code - it had unused events declared - does that error make sense?  I think something is correlating the events with handlers in the Saga, but of course that event isn't there yet...

Comment: Something odd going on ... removing ISaga returns a build error (running dotnet build in VS code at sln level)

Startup.cs(39,19): error CS0311: The type '... WorkflowExecutionSaga' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IRegistrationConfigurator.AddSaga<T>(Action<ISagaConfigurator<T>>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '... WorkflowExecutionSaga' to 'MassTransit.Saga.ISaga'. 

Attaching it directly seems to be OK (it may be a pre-release SDK issue?)

Comment: I don't think so, you're using the wrong method most likely. Check out the unit tests for the container registration code, and make sure you have all the right extension assemblies referenced: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/DependencyInjection_Tests/DependencyInjection_SagaStateMachine.cs